# Force Excel chart to draw before it's scrolled into view using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

We have a very complicated Excel file with many sheets, rows, columns and dependencies, all of which work mostly fine. The file is in auto calc mode. The result of all this stuff is a range which is used to plot a straightforward line chart.

When the data in this range gets updated, the chart does get redrawn when scrolled into view, but there is a very noticeable delay. First, it will not redraw until scrolling is stopped (user releases the mouse button which is used to drag the scroll caret). Secondly, even after that, it's usually about 1-2 seconds. Third, sometimes it takes much longer, we had a user who was able to capture a screenshot of the chart without the data and email it to us, and it only then updated minutes later.

In VBA, we can have a sub executed when the source data changes. Is it possible to somehow trigger the chart to redraw before it's scrolled into view? I tried the following so far:

```
Dim chart As ChartObject
Set chart = shtMainCalc.ChartObjects(1)
Dim series As series
Set series = chart.chart.SeriesCollection(1)
series.Name = series.Name
series.Shadow = series.Shadow
chart.chart.Refresh
chart.Duplicate
Set chart = shtMainCalc.ChartObjects(2)
chart.Delete
Application.Undo
```

Comment: *"Third, sometimes it takes much longer, we had a user who was able to capture a screenshot of the chart without the data and email it to us, and it only then updated minutes later."* - I feel your pain. I've had this very issue before, and my only remedy has been to include a cell somewhere saying "Please allow time for the chart to update" (when switching a category that notoriously takes a while to update the chart source data).

Comment: @dwirony thanks for the suggestion. It's worth adding that the delay of chart redraw is compounded by the length of time it takes to calculate the numbers. Excel hangs for a few seconds as is while it's running all the formulas and **then** users have to wait for chart to update. Not a show stopper but a bad annoyance.

Comment: For sure. Other steps I've taken is to have all my values pre-written on a hidden worksheet for every drop-down option in the list - That way when the user changes their selection, instead of formulas recalculating it's just the source range changing for the chart. Instant updates and my end users are happy :). If you don't have hundreds of possible options then I would definitely suggest doing something like that.